# SSL validation failed for https://states.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2426)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
def initiate_populate_qcreviewtable(data):  
    # call "step function"
    client_step_function.start_execution(
        input=json.dumps(data), 
        stateMachineArn= "{arn of state machine}"
        )
```

I am trying to call step fn from lambda fn 'A' which call other lambda fn 'B',
but when code try to call step fn, it through error (_ssl.c:2426)

I tried to changes scope of code.
but no luck!

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.